# Logic inside List.map

Tags: dart

I want to include logic inside my list mapping. Example:

I can do something like this:

```dart
List projects = urls.map((url) => url.substring(0, 3)).toList();
```

But can I, somehow, do something like this:

```dart
List projects = urls.map((url) {
  if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
    url;
  } else {
    url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
  }
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. What is missing is a `return` statement.
With the short function format (`=>`) `return` is implicit and the result of the expression gets returned. If you use the function block format you have to explicitly return the value you want to have in the result.   Without an explicit `return` `null` is returned.

```dart
List projects = urls.map((url) {
  if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
    return url;
  } else {
    return url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
  }
}).toList();
```

Comment: Seems like I was too quick by station my question: I just solved it using a shorthand if statement: List projects = urls.map((url) => url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? url : url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"))).toList();

Comment: I think it is important to know anyway.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks a lot for your help! You mean a lot to the Dart community, given the fact I see your name popping up on almost every Stackoverflow question about dart